# Is my jade thriving?

Tags: jade

As stated before I bought my jade 2 or 3 weeks ago from a lady over f.b. I have not seen any new growth on my plant. I was wondering what is a sufficient amount of time to wait to see if my plant is thriving? I am planning on pruning and planting leafs so I can have multiples of this beautiful plant. I keep seeing the word porous when talking about planting stems and leafs. What does the word "porous" mean in this context and how is it achieved? If I plant multiple leaves in one pot and one gets root rot can I save the rest of them? Do I have to throw away the soil and start over?

Answer (score 3):

Jade plants do not grow quickly. You mention that is was stressed when you bought it so it could take months before new growth is seen.

To propagate twist a leaf off and let it sit in the pot or on the windowsill for a few days to harden off. The leaf needs to have the wound area dry and calloused. This area is where the roots will come from.

When you propagate a batch of cuttings or leaves once they have started to take root you can carefully pot them up in individual pots or put them back in the main pot.  There is no need to throw the potting soil away. It can be re used many times for this purpose.